# What is the correct pattern with generators and iterators for managing a stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out how to arrange a pair of routines to control writing to a stream using the generator/iterator functions in ES2015. Its a simple logging system to use in nodejs

What I am trying to achieve is a function that external processes can call to write to a log.I am hoping that the new generator/iterator functions means that if it needs to suspend/inside this routine that is transparent.

stream.write should normally return immediately, but can return false to say that the stream is full.  In this case it needs to wait for stream.on('drain',cb) to fire before returning

I am thinking that the actual software that writes to the stream is a generator function which yields when it is ready to accept another request, and that the function I provide to allow external people to call the stream is an interator, but I might have this the wrong way round.

So, something like this

```
var stopLogger = false;
var it = writer();
function writeLog(line) {
  it.next(line);
})

function *writer() {
  while (!stopLogger) {
    line = yield;
    if(!stream.write) {
      yield *WaitDrain();  //can't continue until we get drain
    }
  }
});

function *waitDrain() {
//Not sure what do do here to avoid waiting
  stream.on('drain', () => {/*do I yield here or something*/});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators

I have it backwards.

The code above should be

```
var stopLogger = false;

function *writeLog(line) {
  yield writer(line)
})
var it = writeLog();
function writer(line) {
  if (stopLogger) {
    setTimeout(()=>{it.next();},1};//needed so can get to yield
  } else {
    if(stream.write(line)) {
      setTimeout(()=>{it.next();},1}; //needed so can get to yeild
    }
  } 
}

stream.on('drain', () => {
 it.next();
}
```

I haven't quite tried this, just translated from the above article, and there is some complication around errors etc which the article suggests can be solved by enhancing the it operator to return a promise which can get resolved in a "runGenerator" function,  But it solved my main issue, which was about how should the **pattern** work.